# Extract Number from Constant Output in Bash

Tags: regex, bash, perl, awk, grep

I have a script that producing this kind of output stream in infinite loop:

```
m  17:24:34|ethminer  Speed 377.61 Mh/s    gpu/0 29.01  gpu/1 29.91  gpu/2 30.21  gpu/3 28.71  gpu/4 28.11  gpu/5 27.96  gpu/6 28.71  gpu/7 29.01  gpu/8 28.48  gpu/9 28.86  gpu/10 29.91  gpu/11 29.08  gpu/12 29.68  [A1484+5:R0+0:F0] Time: 04:19
```

I want to extract the integer after "Speed", which is 377 in this case. So far I have, suppose the string is named string:

```
$string |  grep -oP '(?<=Speed).*'
```

I got

```
377.61 Mh/s    gpu/0 29.01  gpu/1 29.91  gpu/2 30.21  gpu/3 28.71  gpu/4 28.11  gpu/5 27.96  gpu/6 28.71  gpu/7 29.01  gpu/8 28.48  gpu/9 28.86  gpu/10 29.91
```

I want to get rid of the trailing string by executing:

```
$string |  grep -oP '(?<=Speed).*'  | grep -o -E '[1-9][0-9][0-9]*'
```

but that regular expression is wrong, it doesn't come out with anything. How can I fix this?

regards

Comment: `$string | | ...` ??? What's that construct?

Comment: oops, it was a typo... I just edited my description.

Comment: maybe `echo $string | grep -oP '(?<=Speed).*'` or even `grep -oP '(?<=Speed).*' <<< $string` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use

```
grep -Po 'Speed\s*\K\d+'
```

Or, to also get the fractional part if it is necessary

```
grep -Po 'Speed\s*\K\d+(\.\d+)?'
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/qZzz5A)

**Details**

- `Speed` - a literal substring
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `\K` - a match reset operator (discarding all text matched so far from the match value)
- `\d+` - 1+ digits
- `(\.\d+)?` - an optional sequence of a `.` and 1+ digits

Answer (score 2):

If the output it *always* like that (i.e. not extra lines in between), a simple `cut -d' ' -f6` will do the job.

Comment: This is indeed the best solution if the output is always the same way formatted.

Comment: Interesting how this can be both the best solution and not an answer, depending on who's reading.

Comment: the format of the string could change in the future, but not for now.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk 'match($0,"Speed [0-9]+.?[0-9]*"){print substr($0,RSTART+6,RLENGTH-6)}'
sed '/Speed/s/.*Speed \([^ ]*\).*/\1/'
```

and if each line is always the same way formatted, you can do:

```
awk '{print $6}' file
```

This means, that every line always has the word speed in column 5 and you want to print column 6.

Comment: I got the sed version working, but the awk part doesn't output anything....

Comment: @ethereal1m what is the problem you are encountering?

Comment: when executing $string | awk 'match($0,"Speed [0-9]+.?[0-9]*"){print substr($0,RSTART+6,RLENGTH-6)}' , I got nothing

Comment: @ethereal1m did you forget `echo`?  You should type `echo "$string" | awk ...`

Comment: oh ok, I was trying to use the awk by piping the output of a script that keep printing the string, which works with sed

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following. Considering that your Input_file is same as shown samples.

```
awk '{sub(/.*Speed /,"");sub(/ .*/,"")} 1' Input_file
```

In case you want to save output into Input_file itself then try following.

```
awk '{sub(/.*Speed /,"");sub(/ .*/,"")} 1' Input_file > temp_file && mv temp_file Input_file
```

Explanation: Adding explanation too here.

```
awk '                  ##awk script starts from here.
{
  sub(/.*Speed /,"")   ##Using sub for substitution operation which will substitute from starting of line to till Speed string with NULL fir current line.
  sub(/ .*/,"")        ##Using sub for substitution of everything starting from space to till end in current line with NULL.
}
1                      ##Mentioning 1 will print edited/non-edited lines in Input_file.
' Input_file           ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Comment: This will fail if the line does not contain `Speed`

Comment: @kvantour, yes please I have added warning in my solution too now.

Answer (score 1):

sed works too.

```
$: echo $string | sed -En '/ Speed /{ s/.* Speed ([0-9]+).*/\1/; p; }'
377
```

Comment: Thanks for the love. :)